# Passing command line java program arguments

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a java server which has to be run via a command line. I want to pass to the server different port numbers to listen to. However I'm not sure how to pass to the ServerSocket class the port number as a command line argument when running the server.

```java
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
    }

    public Server() {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        // I want to specify the port number above as an argument when running the server. 
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: accept an argument on your constructor...

Comment: That's what `String[] args` *is*.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just pass it in:

```
public class Server {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 5000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = args.length > 0? Integer.parseInt(args[0]): DEFAULT_PORT;
        Server server = new Server(port);
    }

    public Server(int port) {
       ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);
       ...
    }
```

You can use a [conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) to determine if a default port should be used in the absence of a value being passed in.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution using a system property:

```java
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(Integer.getInteger("server.socket.port"));
```

Use the following command line:

```
java -Dserver.socket.port=5000 Server
```

The main advantage is that `Integer.getInteger("server.socket.port")` can be accessed anywhere else in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
...
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Server server = new Server( Integer.parseInt( args[0] ) );
}

public Server( int portNumber ) {
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket( portNumber );
}
...
```